# Parse error: unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, parsing

I'm getting this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in ...contact_us.php on line 49.

Can someone help me figure out how to fix it?

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Contact Template
 * The Contact Template file
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Invictus
 * @since Invictus 1.0
 */
wp_reset_query();

wp_enqueue_script('validation');

get_header();

    if(isset($_POST['button_contact_submit'])){

        // store some values
        $email = $_POST['contact_email'];
        $to = get_option_max('contact_email');
        $message  = stripslashes($_POST['contact_message']);
        $content_type="text/plain";

        // Clean the from data
        $from_array = preg_split("/[rn]+/is",trim($_POST['contact_name']),-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        $from = $from_array[0];

        // smtp secure settings
        @ini_set("SMTP", $to);
        @ini_set("smtp_port", 25);
        @ini_set('sendmail_from', $email);

        // build the message
        $msg  = "{$from} ({$email}) has sent you a contact request.rn";
        $msg .= "-----------------------------------------------------rnrn";
        $msg .= "{$message}rn";

        // build the subject
        $subject = "[Contact Request] From ".$_POST['contact_name'];

        // build the headers
        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "rn";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: ' . $content_type . '; charset=UTF-8' . " rn";
        $headers .= 'From: ' . $_POST['contact_name'] . " <".$_POST['contact_email'].">rn";
        $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
        $headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$email."rn";

    if(wp_mail(get_option_max('contact_email'), $subject, $msg, $headers)){
            $resultOk = "<div class="alert"><p class="success"><strong>". __( "Your message has been sent</strong>. Thank you for your request!", MAX_SHORTNAME )."</p></div>";
        }else{
            $resultError = "<div class="alert"><p class="error">". __( "Message delivery failed! Please try again.", MAX_SHORTNAME) ."</p></div>";
        }

    }


?>

<div id="primary" class="template-fullsize">

        <header <?php post_class('entry-header'); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" >

            <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title() ?></h1>

            <?php
            // check if there is a excerpt
            if( max_get_the_excerpt() ){
            ?>
            <h2 class="page-description"><?php max_get_the_excerpt(true) ?></h2>
            <?php } ?>

        </header>

        <div id="content" role="main" class="clearfix">

            <?php the_content() ?>

            <div class="clearfix">

                <?php
                // Display Infotext if enabled
                if( get_option_max('contact_show_text') == "true" ) {
                    $class_1 = "col_2";
                    if( get_option_max('contact_show_info') == 'true' ){
                        $class_1 = "col_one_third";
                    }
                ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $class_1 ?>">
                    <h3><?php stripslashes( get_option_max('contact_sidebar_header',true) )?></h3>
                    <p><?php echo stripslashes( get_option_max('contact_info') ) ?></p>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php
                    // Display Company Infos if enabled
                    if( get_option_max('contact_show_info') == "true" ) {
                        $class_2 = "col_2";
                        if( get_option_max('contact_show_info') == 'true' ){
                            $class_2 = "col_one_third";
                        }
                ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $class_2 ?>">
                    <h3><?php stripslashes( get_option_max('contact_info_header',true) )?></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <?php if ( get_option_max('contact_adress_1') != "" ) echo '<li>'. get_option_max('contact_adress_1') . '</li>' ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option_max('contact_adress_2') != "" ) echo '<li>'. get_option_max('contact_adress_2') . '</li>' ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option_max('contact_phone') != "" ) echo '<li>'. __('Phone', MAX_SHORTNAME) . ': '. get_option_max('contact_phone') . '</li>' ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option_max('contact_fax') != "" ) echo '<li>'. __('Fax', MAX_SHORTNAME) . ': '. get_option_max('contact_fax') . '</li>' ?>
                        <?php if ( get_option_max('contact_info_email') != "" ) echo '<li>'. __('eMail', MAX_SHORTNAME) . ': <a href="mailto:' . get_option_max('contact_info_email') . '">'. get_option_max('contact_info_email') . '</a></li>' ?>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>


                <?php $class_3 = "col_one_third col_one_third_last"; ?>
                <div class="<?php echo $class_3 ?>">
                <?php if(!isset($resultOk)){ ?>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($resultError)){
                            echo($resultError);
                        }
                    ?>
                        <form id="contactForm" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    <label><?php _e( "Your Name", MAX_SHORTNAME) ?>: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <input name="contact_name" type="text" class="required requiredField" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label><?php _e( "Your eMail", MAX_SHORTNAME) ?>: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <input name="contact_email" type="text" class="required requiredField email" />
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <label><?php _e( "Your Message", MAX_SHORTNAME) ?>: <span class="required">*</span></label>
                                    <textarea name="contact_message" cols="50" rows="5" class="required requiredField "></textarea>
                                </li>
                                <li><button type="submit" name="button_contact_submit"><?php _e( "Send Message", MAX_SHORTNAME) ?></button></li>
                            </ul>
                            <p><small><em>(*) <?php _e( "Required Fields", MAX_SHORTNAME) ?></em></small></p>
                        </form>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php
                    if(isset($resultOk)){
                        echo($resultOk);
                    }
                ?>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->
```

Comment: It's best to figure out which line is the one reported in the error and tell us. By my count, which may not be correct, it is the line starting with `$resultOk =`. That line has a bunch of unescaped `"` in your HTML string, which is prematurely closing your string and mistakenly reopening new strings for PHP, which is probably the cause of your error. The `$resultError =` line has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(wp_mail(get_option_max('contact_email'), $subject, $msg, $headers)){
        $resultOk = "<div class="alert"><p class="success"><strong>". __( "Your message has been sent</strong>. Thank you for your request!", MAX_SHORTNAME )."</p></div>";
    }else{
        $resultError = "<div class="alert"><p class="error">". __( "Message delivery failed! Please try again.", MAX_SHORTNAME) ."</p></div>";
    }

}
```

You're using double quotes without escaping them, you can either escape them by using backslashes or replace the double quotes with single quotes

Change it to:

```
if(wp_mail(get_option_max('contact_email'), $subject, $msg, $headers)){
        $resultOk = '<div class="alert"><p class="success"><strong>'. __( "Your message has been sent</strong>. Thank you for your request!", MAX_SHORTNAME )."</p></div>";
    }else{
        $resultError = '<div class="alert"><p class="error">'. __( "Message delivery failed! Please try again.", MAX_SHORTNAME) ."</p></div>";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Error is here

```
<div class="alert"><p class="success">
```

This should be like this

```
<div class='alert'><p class='success'>
```

double qoutes to single qoutes

I hope this will solve the issue